# dd() reads values that var_dump() can't read

Tags: php, laravel

In one of my controllers I call a view with the variable `$members`:

```
$members = Member::orderBy("created_at", "desc")->get();
```

Then in the view I loop over all the member's groups:

```
@foreach ($members as $group)
    <?php $group = $group->group(); ?>
    <b>{{ $group->title }}</b> // fails
@endforeach
```

This throws a `Trying to get property of non-object` exception. If I do

```
@foreach ($member as $group)
    <?php $group = $group->group(); ?>
    <?php dd($group); ?>       // works
    <b>{{ $group->title }}</b> // fails
@endforeach
```

I can see all the `attributes` array populated with all the values I want. Why can `dd()` read values I can't read using `{{ $var }}`?

---

```
@foreach ($member as $group)
    <?php $group = $group->group(); ?>
    <?php var_dump($group); ?> // fails
    <b>{{ $group->title }}</b> // fails
@endforeach
```

fails as well.

Comment: I'm confused what now really works and what not.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I edited my question. Should be clearer now. Please tell me if it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the error. For some reason I cannot read `$group->value`, but `$group["value"]` works. It may be that `group` is a keyword.